# ¿Cómo solucionar Laravel 4.2 Array to string conversion seleccionando un valor de db dentro de un foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Tengo un foreach de necesidades de los usuarios y dentro del foreach necesito asociar el nombre del autor de cada necesidad. Lo hago de esta forma:

```
      foreach ($needs as $need) {


          $need_owner = $need->owner;

          $the_owner = DB::table('users')
             ->select('name_surname')
             ->where('id', '=', $need_owner)
             ->get();

       echo $need_owner

       //....
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Array to string conversion (View: ...

Utilizo Laravel 4.2. El `$need->owner` es un id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando get(), el cual obtiene una colección de elementos, lo que debes utilizar es first(), para obtener el primer elemento de dicha colección.

```
      $the_owner = DB::table('users')
         ->select('name_surname')
         ->where('id', '=', $need_owner)
         ->first();
```

Comment: Gracias por tú respuesta ! Ahora me sucede este problema: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: ¿cuándo aparece ese error?

Comment: Si hago `var_dump($the_owner->name_surname);` me funciona, pero si hago `echo $the_owner` no ...

Comment: aparece en \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php linea 41

Comment: Me funciono! Solo tenia que poner esto: `echo $the_owner->name_surname;` en vez de `echo $the_owner;` a secas.

Comment: Bueno, entenderás que al ser una colección, `$the_owner` es un objeto, por lo cual si intentas hacer echo, te va a mostrar ese error. Si haces `echo $the_owner->name_surname` deberías obtener lo que creo que necesitas.